# Google App Engine application to private cloud

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, autoscaling

I have a Google App Engine application that I have developed in Python that leverages Datastore.  My customer now needs to run this application within a localized infrastructure due to privacy concerns.  Some key requirements are: autoscaling, low latency and ability to store noSQL data.  What are my options?

Answer (score 4):

You've basically chosen the wrong platform I think, but AppScale would help you do what you want:

http://www.appscale.com/

> AppScale Systems, Inc. develops and supports AppScale, the world’s
>   leading open source rapid development model for building scalable web
>   and mobile applications. AppScale gives you the freedom to run your
>   App Engine application across all public and private clouds or on your
>   own virtual or physical infrastructure. AppScale leverages the App
>   Engine API to allow DEVS to quickly focus on the business logic of the
>   application and frees your OPS from unwieldy software stacks. AppScale
>   Systems is proud to be a Google Cloud Technology Partner.

An alternative would be to continue to run in the GAE cloud itself, but restrict access via logins and/or IP address etc.